How to generate output of HuggingFace PEFT model with previous message history as context?
I am trying to generate text from my fine-tuned Llama3 model which uses the PEFT AutoPeftModelForCausalLM library while also passing in previous message history.
This is how I am currently generating responses without previous message history:
def get_response(input):
  inputs = tokenizer(["""Generate a response to the input
  ### Input:
  {}
  ### Response:""".format(input)], return_tensors = "pt").to("cuda")

  outputs = model.generate(input_ids=inputs["input_ids"].to("cuda"), max_new_tokens=32)
  response = tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)[0]

  return response

And this is how I defined the model and tokenizer variables:
model = AutoPeftModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("huggingface-user/outputs").to("cuda")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("unsloth/llama-3-8b-bnb-4bit")

I want to be able to pass in something like:
previous_messages = [
{"role": "user", "content": message1},
{"role": "assistant", "content": message2},
{"role": "user", "content": message3},
{"role": "assistant", "content": message4},
]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

You may wish to look into using Chat Templates.
